# /bin/dash: check whether $1 is a number

Tags: shell, regular-expression, string, dash

What would be the best way to check whether $1 is an integer in /bin/dash ?

In bash, I could do:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]+)$ ]]
```

But that does not seem to be POSIX compliant and dash does not support that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following detect integers, positive or negative, and work under `dash` and are POSIX:

#### Option 1

```
echo "$1" | grep -Eq '^[+-]?[0-9]+$' && echo "It's an integer"
```

#### Option 2

```
case "${1#[+-]}" in
    ''|*[!0-9]*)
        echo "Not an integer" ;;
    *)
        echo "Integer" ;;
esac
```

Or, with a little use of the `:` (nop) command:

```
! case ${1#[+-]} in *[!0-9]*) :;; ?*) ! :;; esac && echo Integer
```

Comment: What if the string contains newlines? `foo\n123\nbar` isn't an integer, but would pass this test.

Comment: The grep version, that is.  The case version looks correct.

Answer (score 5):

Whether `dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, POSIX `sh`, or `posh` (*"a reimplementation of the Bourne shell"* `sh`) ; the `case` construct is the most widely available and reliable:

```
case $1 in (*[!0-9]*|"") false ;; (*) true ;; esac
```

Comment: Did you test this under `dash`?  It works for me under `bash` but  not `dash`.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on my system also with `dash`; to interrogate the result I added `echo $?` after the case command.

Comment: I did the same (Debian stable) but no joy.   For a complete example that works for me under my dash, see my _Option 2_.

Comment: Hmm, I have no original bourne shell available to test. The docs that I inspected about "features [in ksh] not in bourne shell" at least does not mention it, so I assume it was there. No? - Then omit the leading parenthesis. - OTOH, `posh` ("a reimplementation of the Bourne shell") has also no problem with that solution, though.

Comment: @Janis - yeah, `posh` handles it correctly because it is POSIX, but ye olde Bourne shell predates the standard - and `(pattern)`. That said, *(and as Stéphane taught me)* other shells fail to handle `pattern)` correctly when the `case` statement is enclosed in `$(`cmdsub`)` parens. Try `: "$(case $PWD in broken) :;;esac)"` in `zsh`, for example.

Comment: @mikeserv; There are several reasons why I use always matching parentheses in `case`; one reason is the bug you describe, another one that in editors that have features that rely on matching parenthesis (vim) it gives much better support, and not least I find it personally better legible to have them matching. - WRT `posh` being POSIX; well, the quote from the man page that I gave suggested something else, but one can't rely on such informal statements anyway, I guess. Old bourne shell is anyway not that significant any more now that we're in POSIX era.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-eq` test on the string, with itself:

```
$ dash -c 'a="a"; if [ "$a" -eq "$a" ] ; then echo number; else echo not a number; fi' 
dash: 1: [: Illegal number: a
not a number
$ dash -c 'a="0xa"; if [ "$a" -eq "$a" ] ; then echo number; else echo not a number; fi'
dash: 1: [: Illegal number: 0xa
not a number
$ dash -c 'a="-1"; if [ "$a" -eq "$a" ] ; then echo number; else echo not a number; fi'
number
```

If the error message is a problem, redirect error output to `/dev/null`:

```
$ dash -c 'a="0xa"; [ "$a" -eq "$a" ] 2>/dev/null|| echo no'
no
```

Comment: It would also say that `" 023  "` is a number. Note that it works with dash, but not all other POSIX shells as the behaviour is unspecified if the operands are note decimal integers. For instance with ksh, it would say that `SHLVL` or `1+1` is a number.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX system, you can use [expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html):

```
$ a=a
$ expr "$a" - 0 >/dev/null 2>&1
$ [ "$?" -lt 2 ] && echo Integer || echo Not Integer
```

Comment: It will say that 0 is not an integer (and say -12 is which the OP's bash solution would have rejected). Some `expr` implementations will say that 9999999999999999999 is not an integer. POSIX gives no warranty that this will work. In practice, on a GNU system at least, it will say that "length" is an integer.

Comment: In my test, it works at least in Debian and OSX. It does say integer for 0. Posix ensure $a must be a valid expression (integer) for expr do arithmetic.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I had overlooked your test for $? < 2. Still `expr 9999999999999999999 + 0` gives me a 3 exit status and `expr -12 + 0` and `expr length + 0` give me a 0 exit status with GNU expr (`+ string` forces `string` to be considered as a string with GNU `expr`. `expr "$a" - 0` would work better).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, yes, updated my answer. I think `-12` is a valid integer, and `9999999999999999999` gave an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as an arithmetic expansion, and see if it works.  Actually, you need to be a bit stricter than that, because arithmetic expansions would ignore leading and trailing spaces, for instance.  So do an arithmetic expansion, and make sure that the expanded result matches the original variable exactly.

```
check_if_number()
{
    if [ "$1" = "$((${1}))" ] 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Number!"
    else
        echo "not a number"
    fi
}
```

This would also accept negative numbers - if you really mean to exclude them, add an extra check for `$((${1} >= 0))`.

Comment: dash does not have `[[`

Comment: @glennjackman Whoops.  Does it have `$(( ... ))` ?  If so, my answer should still be materially correct, I just need to add some extra quoting.

Comment: it's your answer: go find out.

Comment: Looks like it does, so my updated version should do the trick.  I don't have dash to test it out, though - so let me know if I missed anything else.

Comment: I tried: `check_if_number 1.2` and the function returned: 
`dash: 3: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "1.2"`

Comment: That would say 01 is not a number.

Comment: @John1024, odd - I would have expected the 2>/dev/null to squelch that message.  I guess I'll have to test with dash later.

Comment: `2> /dev/null` only redirects the errors of the `[` command, not that of the expansion of `$((...))` used to construct that `[` command line.

Comment: Ah well.  I'll admit that using "case" is a better answer than this, in any event.

Comment: Do `ck_int() { [ "$1" -eq "$(($1))" ]; } 2>/dev/null` and it will return correctly without making any noise - because the stderr for the `{` compound command `}` in which the math expansion occurs is redirected. But a bad math expansion will kill a non-interactive shell and may be dangerous for other reasons *(try `ck_int PATH=0`)*. Instead - in `dash` at least - do `ck_int(){ [ "${1##*[!0-9]}" -eq "${1#[+-]}" ]; } 2>/dev/null` and you will get a silent boolean test which returns 0 for true or other than 0 for false.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with `expr`?

```
if expr match "$1" '^\([0-9]\+\)$' > /dev/null; then
  echo "integer"
else 
  echo "non-integer"
fi
```

Comment: neither `match` nor `\+` are POSIX. It would also say 0 is not a number. You want `expr "x$1" : 'x[0-9]\{1,\}$'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function using the same method as [*muru*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198249/165517):

```
IsInteger()      # usage: IsInteger string
{               #  returns: flag
        [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2> /dev/null
}
```

Example:

```
p= n=2a3; IsInteger $n || p="n't" ; printf "'%s' is%s an integer\n" "$n" "$p"
p= n=23;  IsInteger $n || p="n't" ; printf "'%s' is%s an integer\n" "$n" "$p"
```

Output:

```
'2a3' isn't an integer
'23' is an integer
```